# PHP: Controller and View / where to place recursive method

Tags: php, view, recursion, model

Model: I have a table like id:name:parentId. The parentId references
    to the id. Simple recursion to build a tree.

In example:

1. 1:root:null
2. 2:Heading1:1
3. 3:Heading2:1
4. 4:subheading1.1:2

In my controller I would now call the Database and pass the data
    through to the view. If I would do that then I would have a function
    inside my view. I do not like functionality in my view :).

The other approach would be to sort that somehow. But would this really make a difference?

- For doing that I would have to use helping fields to know which level I am in. So I could iterate over the sorted array.
- Or  the other approach: Multidimensional arrays. Maybe pointless because I have no idea how deep that tree is going to be.

Would be thankful for any recommendations. 
Thanks in advance.

edit: im receiving the data as objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the trends in MVC framework based designs (fat model, slim controller), I would recommend to use your Model to fetch the data and deliver a nested data set (a mulitidimensional array) to the controller/view. It doesn't matter how deep the hierarchy will be, it will be finite.

As the question is a bit broadly asked, it's not clear what sort of data it is, neither whether you're always going to need the whole data at once or just some relative chunk of it. Either way I suppose you'd like to keep the hierarchy, so if you're not comfortable iterating through nested arrays there's always the alternative of using (Std)Objects.

Comment: Thats right! But if I pass that data I will have to walk through all the dimensions of that array in my view. It must be recursive again?! So I doubled the work. Or maybe u meant sth different. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: thx for your answer. Ill  Can u maybe do a little example. Updated my question as well.

Comment: Sure, can you also provide an example of your objects as well as an example of the desired output?

Comment: On a second thought, that would be a matter of a different question.

Answer (score 1):

If you look [here](http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/) you see a nested tree (table). Click on the `To Array` button. You will see an array like this:

```
    '0' ...
        'item_id' ...
        'parent_id' => "none"
        'depth' => "0"
        'left' => "1"
        'right' => "22"
    '1' ...
        'item_id' => "1"
        'parent_id' ...
        'depth' => "1"
        'left' => "2"
        'right' => "7"
```

Notice the `left` and `right` explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)

In this way you also can get depth and a part of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Build multidimensional array in your model and pass it to the view.

You can make multidimensional array without recursion with pointers.

```
// collect tree
$res=$Conn->query('SELECT id, name, parentId FROM tree');

// if your root node has parent 0
$tree[0]->children=array();

// build into one array
// every node is found from its $tree[parentId]->children[id]
// and from $tree[id]
foreach($res as $row)
{
    $tree[$row['id']]->data=$row;

    if(!isset($tree[$row['id']]->children))
        $tree[$row['id']]->children=array();

    $tree[$row['parentId']]->children[$row['id']]=&$tree[$row['id']];
}
```

Comment: It's a generally bad idea to handle the data in the controller. That's why there's the model.

Comment: yeah, mixed model and controller :D Lesson learnt morning coffee first stack second.